# How to using moment compare dates?

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, antd

```
render: (khoadaotao: khoadaotaoType): Element => {
  let ngayBatDau: Moment = moment(khoadaotao?.ngayBatDau);
  let ngayKetThuc: Moment = moment(khoadaotao?.ngayKetThuc);
  let currentDate: Moment = moment();
  if (
    ngayKetThuc.isSameOrAfter(currentDate, "day") &&
    ngayBatDau.isSameOrBefore(currentDate, "day")
  ) {
    return <Tag color="green">Active</Tag>;
  } else if (ngayBatDau.isAfter(currentDate, "day")) {
    return <Tag color="blue"> Soon</Tag>;
  }
  return <Tag color="magenta">Expired</Tag>;
};
```

I have a start date and an end date. I want to use moment to compare from that can set for the state of my course, what did I do wrong?
start date: ngayBatDau, end date: ngayKetThuc.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to remove the `"day"` part from the comparisons, as that compares only the day of the dates.